# matplotlib popup window removal

Tags: matplotlib

[image]When creating a figure, I get a popup window " 'figure 1' is ready" etc. This did not exist in previous versions of matplotlib (I am using spyder). These temoprarily block the screen until they disapear after a few seconds which is annoying. How can I stop these popups (sample image attached) ?

Comment: I'm frequently working with Spyder and have never seen such window. The least you need to do is to state the version of Spyder in use, the operating system and the Python and PyQt version you use.

Comment: I'm using spyder 3.2.8 on ubuntu. When you refer to PyQt, do you mean the graphics backend? I choose "autotmatic" there.

Comment: No I meant PyQt because Spyder is written in Qt. But seeing the screenshot this is probably not relevant. It seems this is a feature of Spyder, although I'm using spyder 3.2.8 as well, but on windows, where this does not happen. I suppose you can bring this up on the spyder issue tracker (but make sure to include all relevant details and the exact steps to reproduce when doing so).

Comment: One thing I can say is that if I change the graphics backend to Tkinter, this does not happen. However, the Tkinter figures don't include the "edit axis" icon on the toolbar which I find useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a Gnome feature that causes this popup to appear rather than have a window in the background pop up and steal focus.

The underlying cause is that each time the graph is drawn, it steals focus and comes to the front.  Gnome extension overrides this kind of focus stealing, but shows the popup.

For more info on this, see https://superuser.com/questions/644850/disable-window-is-ready-notification-in-gnome-shell

The fix I used was to keep matplotlib from stealing window focus, which is covered by this question: [Make interactive matplotlib window not pop to front on each update (Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729092/make-interactive-matplotlib-window-not-pop-to-front-on-each-update-windows-7)