# How to keep matplotlib from stealing focus?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looping through a bunch of images and need to enter a label in the terminal when each image is displayed, kind of like this:

```
for pic in pics:
  fig = plt.figure()
  plt.imshow(pic)
  lbl = input()
  ...
  plt.close(fig)
```

The issue is that the figure steals the focus, so instead of just typing I need to keep clicking on the terminal first, then typing.  Can this be avoided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Try to switch backend from tk to qt

   ```
   matplotlib.use("Qt5agg")
   ```
2. Or use your own pause or use animate function

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45734500/12366487